# Convert custom string to xml

Tags: java

Custom string format to xml help needed. Java and C#.

`[Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT1(A)][Key1(1)][Key2(2)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT1(B)][Key1(1)][Key2(2)][Key3(3)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT1(C)][Key1(4)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT2(A)][Key1(1)][Key2(2)][Key3(3)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT2(B)][Key1(4)][Key2(5)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD1(Z)][OBJECT1(A)][Key1(7)][Key2(8)][Key3(9)]`
`[Node(X)][CHILD1(Z)][OBJECT2(A)][Key1(15)][Key2(18)]`

There may be 'n' number of string rows like the above samples.
What is the best method to serialize this to an xml file as below

If the below shown xml is also incorrect, then please advise the correct format as well. 
I tried serializing using some examples provided in stackoverflow and code project, but I'm unable 
to get the xml in the below format. Trying to do it in java and c#. Thank you all in advance.

```
[X]
    [Y]  
        [OBJECT1]
            [A]
                <Key1>1</Key1>
                <Key2>2</Key2>
            [/A]
            [B]
            <Key1>2</Key1>
            <Key2>2</Key2>
            <Key3>3</Key3>
        [/B]
        [C]
            <Key1>4</Key1>
        [/C]
    [/OBJECT1]
    [OBJECT2]
        [A]
            <Key1>1</Key1>
            <Key2>2</Key2>
            <Key3>3</Key3>
        [/A]
        [B]
            <Key1>4</Key1>
            <Key2>5</Key2>
        [/B]
    [/OBJECT2]
    [/Y]
    [Z]
        [OBJECT1]
        [A]
            <Key1>7</Key1>
            <Key2>8</Key2>
            <Key2>9</Key2>
            [/A]
        [/OBJECT1]
        [OBJECT2]
        [A]
            <Key1>15</Key1>
            <Key2>18</Key2>
        [/A]
        [/OBJECT2]
    [/Z]
[/X]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like XML, and where is your code? What exactly are you having trouble with? And Java or C# - choose one, they're unrelated.

Comment: @Mat - Sorry if my question was confusing. I have n number of custom formatted strings. [Key(Value)][Key(Value)]... with variable number of [Key(Value)] pairs. I would like to serialize this to an xml file. As I mentioned in my initial post, if the xml format is incorrect, please ignore it and advise the best way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: oops, forgot to mention. This is on Java. Thanks.

Comment: And where is the code you have so far? Where specifically are you stuck? (There's literally millions of documents describing what XML is on the Web, and truckloads others about how to manipulate XML in Java.)

Comment: So, if input is: `[Node(x)]` output should be: `<x/>` ?

Comment: One should think and understand about the time zone differences before downvoting a question, with out giving enough time to add the information about research done before asking the question in this forum. And every one is not an expert in everything. I'm also a human being with exceptional knowledge in some thing like you, but a nerd in coding. All question will not be unique and all will not be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a parser class for your purpose:

```
public class XmlSerializer {

private String input;
private Element currentNode, currentChild, currentObject;
private Map<String, Element> nodes;
private Map<Element, Map<String, Element>> children, objects;

/**
 * Initializes the serializer with the given input string.
 * @param  input input string
 */
public XmlSerializer(String input) {
    this.input = input;
    this.nodes = new HashMap<String, Element>();
    this.children = new HashMap<Element, Map<String,Element>>();
    this.objects = new HashMap<Element, Map<String,Element>>();
}

/**
 * Parses the input string and returns the XML document.
 * @return XML document
 */
public Document parseDocument()
throws ParserConfigurationException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.+?)\\((.+?)\\)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    Document dom = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element root = dom.createElement("root");
    dom.appendChild(root);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);

        if ("Node".equals(key)) {
            currentNode = parseElement(key, value, dom, root, nodes, children);
        } else if (currentNode != null && key.startsWith("CHILD")) {
            currentChild = parseElement(key, value, dom, currentNode,
                    children.get(currentNode), objects);
        } else if (currentChild != null && key.startsWith("OBJECT")) {
            currentObject = parseElement(key, value, dom, currentChild,
                    objects.get(currentChild), null);
        } else {
            Element property = parseProperty(key, value, dom);
            currentObject.appendChild(property);
        }
    }

    return dom;
}

/**
 * Returns the parsed XML document as string.
 * @return XML document as string
 */
public String toXML()
throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    Source source = new DOMSource(parseDocument());
    Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return writer.getBuffer().toString();
}

/**
 * Parses an element.
 * @param  key      key in {@code [key(value)]} string
 * @param  value    value in {@code [key(value)]} string
 * @param  dom      DOM
 * @param  parent   parent element to add this element to
 * @param  cache    cache for the parsed element
 * @param  subCache sub-cache to initialize (optional)
 * @return the element
 */
private Element parseElement(String key, String value, Document dom, Element parent,
        Map<String, Element> cache, Map<Element, Map<String, Element>> subCache) {
    Element el = cache.get(value);
    if (el == null) {
        el = dom.createElement(value);
        cache.put(key, el);
        parent.appendChild(el);
        if (subCache != null)
            subCache.put(el, new HashMap<String, Element>());
    }
    return el;
}

/**
 * Parses a property element.
 * @param  key   key in {@code [key(value)]} string
 * @param  value value in {@code [key(value)]} string
 * @param  dom   DOM
 * @return the element
 */
private Element parseProperty(String key, String value, Document dom) {
    Element property = dom.createElement(key);
    property.setTextContent(value);
    return property;
}

}
```

Use it like this:

```
String input;  // [Node(X)][CHILD0(Y)][OBJECT1(A)][Key1(1)][Key2(2)]...
String xml = new XmlSerializer(input).toXML();
System.out.println(xml);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <X>
    <Y>
      <A>
        <Key1>1</Key1>
        <Key2>2</Key2>
      </A>
    </Y>
    <Y>
      <B>
        <Key1>1</Key1>
        <Key2>2</Key2>
        <Key3>3</Key3>
      </B>
    </Y>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Y>
      <C>
        <Key1>4</Key1>
      </C>
    </Y>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Y>
      <A>
        <Key1>1</Key1>
        <Key2>2</Key2>
        <Key3>3</Key3>
      </A>
    </Y>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Y>
      <B>
         <Key1>4</Key1>
         <Key2>5</Key2>
      </B>
    </Y>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Z>
      <A>
        <Key1>7</Key1>
        <Key2>8</Key2>
        <Key3>9</Key3>
      </A>
    </Z>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Z>
      <A>
        <Key1>15</Key1>
        <Key2>18</Key2>
      </A>
    </Z>
  </X>
</root>
```

Go from here and optimize it a little, for example if you don't want repeated `<X>...</X>` nodes.

Comment: Thanks very much jabu. appreciate your time and effort.